# How to use sed to extract numbers from a comma separated string?

Tags: regex, sed

I managed to extract the following response and comma separate it. It's comma seperated string and I'm only interested in comma separated values of the account_id's. How do you pattern match using `sed`?

**Input**: `ACCOUNT_ID,711111111119,ENVIRONMENT,dev,ACCOUNT_ID,111111111115,dev`

Expected **Output**: `711111111119, 111111111115`

My `$input` variable stores the input

I tried the below but it joins all the numbers and I would like to preserve the comma ','

```
echo $input | sed -e "s/[^0-9]//g"
```

Comment: Why sed specifically? What about other tools?

Comment: You may use `sed -e 's/[^,0-9]*//g' -e 's/,,*/,/g' -e 's/^,*//' -e 's/,*$//'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're better served with `awk`:

```
awk -v FS=, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/[0-9]/){printf sep $i;sep=","}}'
```

If you really want `sed`, you can go for

```
sed -e "s/[^0-9]/,/g" -e "s/,,*/,/g" -e "s/^,\|,$//g"
```

Comment: Always use `printf "%s", $i` instead of `printf $i` as the latter will fail when `$i` contains `printf` formatting characters like `%s`,

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}
{
    c = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i == "ACCOUNT_ID") {
            printf "%s%s", (c++ ? OFS : ""), $(i + 1)
        }
    }
    print ""
}' file
711111111119,111111111115
```